# Using a HashMap's/HashSet's hashCode() function to sort data

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashset

I have been trying to think of creative ways to use hashing functions and hashmaps. Right now I am figuring out if there is a way to both store and sort data by forcing collisions.

Say for instance, the input is a giant list of Strings and the goal is to print out every string that is X length. If I store all the Strings in a HashSet with the HashCode...

```
  @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return s.length();
   }
```

I would then have everything indexed by it's length. Then in theory if I wanted all length 3 strings I get the list of strings indexed at 3.

How would I get the list at the index? Would this even be a good idea?

Comment: Hashes are not designed for sorting.  They are designed for quick lookup and retrieval.

Comment: Do not do anything with `hashCode`, except as a means to determine if two objects are not equal. Sorting based on hash code is just misuse of the method.

Comment: Neither HashSet nor HashMap are indexed collections. If you want all the strings which have a length of 3, create a HashMap<Integer, List<String>> where the key is the length, and the value is the list of all the strings with the same length.

Comment: Agree with the previous comments. If you wanted to do something like this, don't override `hashCode()`, instead just put them in a `List` of `List`s, inserting into the first list by the length of the `String` as index. In any case, you can't subclass `String`, then class is `final`. Over use a `Map` where key is the length as JB Nizet said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the goal `hashcode()` is aimed for. Also, in HashMaps, the objects are NOT sorted. Internally yes, because they are stored in arrays (by the reminder of hashcode), but the class doesn't provide you any access by index to its elements.

But you can extend a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` , where you can map a length `n` to a list of strings of lenght `n`, and implement this additional method:

```
public void add(String s) {
    // null check here 
    List<String> list = get(s.length);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        put (s.lenght, list);
    }
    list.add(s);
}
```

then use it like this:

```
map.add("hello");
map.add("world");
map.add("knife");
map.add("good");
map.add("day");
map.get(5); // return list of hello, world, knife
```

Comment: There's no need to "extend" any `Map`. Using `map.computeIfAbsent(someString.length(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(someString);` should be enough.